# How to grant azure active directory B2C users permissions on storage account containers?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-b2c

I ‘m working with Active Directory B2C and Storage account in azure.
Is there a way to grant for each connected user, an ownership of a **dedicated container only**, in order to perform action such as read, write, delete and list files?

I need some help to achieve this requirement using a c# sdk preferably.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: You need to add b2c user as guest user to the current aad. And this can only do on portal.

Comment: Hi, If my answer answered your question, can you [mark it as the answer](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png) to end the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the user in your B2C AAD to your current ADD as the guest.

For example, the email of my B2C user is bowman@testbowmanb2c.onmicrosoft.com.

I add it to the current ADD:

[image]

[image]

Then please go to the storage account in your current AAD. Choose this:

[image]

And for the operation of data, the user need this role:

[image]

Please notice that, even we can use powershell to add RBAC roles, we still need to use portal to add guest user.

Comment: I am little confused by the separation between subscriptions and B2C Tenant.
If for each created user via my app I will add this user as a guest manually via portal azure, I would rather create new subscription for my B2C Tenant and Create my storage account in B2C directory. 
Created users are marked as “User type: Members” in B2C active directory Tenant. 
Do you think I can apply RBAC on members accounts not Guests?

Comment: @HoussineHASSAYOUN Hi, that is impossible. Because in fact you have a new domain. Only in same domain you can add user can be member.

Comment: I think what may be the underling question is what is the point of a B2C tenant if a signed-in user is not authorized to do anything within Azure?