# How to authorize Azure B2C user to read blob storage

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to recreate something I did in AWS using Cognito User Pool and Identity Pool. The user was able to login and receive temporary tokens that allowed direct access to an s3 bucket. See [here](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/auth-in-serverless-apps.html) for more info on that. I would like my B2C users to be able to login to my SPA and list containers and blobs and get blobs. I've successfully implemented logging in using MSAL (@azure/msal-browser) with auth flow, but I cannot figure out how to provide access tokens for the storage account (or ANY azure resource for that matter). I've run around in circles in the documentation for days, so if you link a docs page, I'd appreciate some elaboration because I'm obviously not understanding something.

Comment: Side note: I'm very confused if RBAC comes into play at all for B2C users. The documentation often blurs the line between internal employees and customers logging into a SaaS, so it's been difficult to gauge which aspects of Azure apply to all directories or only just non-B2C directories.

Comment: Depending on how you access the storage, I would think you would not want to give direct access to blob storage from a B2C account. For example the B2C account could access an API and a user assigned managed identity would access the storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing Storage is not supported with token obtained using B2C user flow or custom policy [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/31947/get-access-to-azure-blob-storage-and-key-vault-fro.html): As u not able to create Storage account in  your azure ad b2c tenant .you need to create storage in azure  and You need to add the user in your B2C AAD to your current ADD as the guest to access the blob storage .

For example :the email of my B2C user is bowman@testbowmanb2c.onmicrosoft.com.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And for the operation of data, the user need this role:

[image]

For more details refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61714158/how-to-grant-azure-active-directory-b2c-users-permissions-on-storage-account-con)

Comment: Thanks, I am marking this as the answer to my question but I am probably going to do something else because this does not seem friendly for my users to sign up for two different tenants. What is the point of the B2C tenant if you cannot authorize the B2C user to use any azure services??

Comment: @dem7w2 Hi, how did you resolve this? I am having the same issue

Comment: @TM I’m sorry I’m too far disconnected from this project to remember. From checking the front end code, I can tell you I’m using an instance of InteractiveBrowserCredential passed into BlobServiceClient as the 2nd param, but no idea about the Azure configuration.

Comment: @dem7w2, i posted a workaround for this in case it makes sense to anyone else

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. Not being able to deal with it, i had to resolve it going a different way. My SPA app first makes a call to the API and the API that has full permissions creates a container and a SAS token for that container with create/write access for 5 mins. The api then returns the full URI of the blob to be created along with the SAS token to the UI. Then the UI uses that URI to make an authorized call to create a new blob in that container.

Here is the POC code i used to validate that this solution is working.

1st: the code for creating the full blob URI containing the SAS token:

```c#
        using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
        using Azure.Storage;
        using Azure.Storage.Sas;

        Guid blobId = Guid.NewGuid();
        string blobName = blobId.ToString();
        string containerName = _requestStateService.CurrentUserId.ToString();
        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxxxx;AccountKey=yyyyyy;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
                
        IDictionary<string, string> containerMetadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        containerMetadata["test"] = "test meta";
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        if (!await containerClient.ExistsAsync())
        {
            containerClient = await blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(
              containerName, metadata: containerMetadata);
        }
        
        
        BlobSasBuilder containerSasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
        {
            BlobContainerName = containerName,
            Resource = "c",
            ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
        };
        containerSasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Write | Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasPermissions.Create | BlobSasPermissions.Tag);
        var containerSASToken = containerClient.GenerateSasUri(containerSasBuilder).AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[1].ToString();
        var containerSASToken = await CreateContainerSASToken(containerClient, containerName);
        var blobSASURI = containerClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri + "/" + blobName + "?" + containerSASToken;
        
        return blobSASURI;
```

2nd: the code that this URI can be used by another app like the UI to upload the blob:

```
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        var content = new StringContent("Write new file");
        content.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2020-04-08");
        content.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
        content.Headers.Add("x-ms-meta-test1", "test meta 1");
        content.Headers.Add("x-ms-meta-test2", "test meta 2");
        content.Headers.Add("x-ms-tags", "tag1=aaa&tag2=bbb");
        var response = await client.PutAsync(blobSASURI, content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

For the container i chose to have one per user where i put all the blobs of a user.

To read the blobs i can create SAS tokens every time they need to be fetched.
I know this is not the most simple solution but this it meets my needs for authorization since the API needs to be called first and it can check and authorize the user and what blobs he should be able to access.