# How to authorise Azure B2C users to read Azure Storage Blob

Tags: next.js, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-b2c, next-auth, azure-authentication

I'm building a SPA web app (Next.js). My users are logging in via AAD B2C (by using NextAuth.js).

We have files stored in Azure Blob Storage which is created in the same tenant as the B2C. The users are added to different AAD Groups which have RBAC access to the Storage containers.

How do I create userDelegated SAS token for the logged in users to authorise them to read the files?
If userDelegated is no the way to go, how do I secure that only users with correct RBAC get read access to the files?

(Lets assume all the files are shown on the screen)

I've run around in circles in the MS documentations for days, and have been reading here on StackOverflow with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing Key Vault & Storage is not supported with token obtained using B2C user flow or custom policy. You can request a token using same way that you used with standard Azure AD i.e. using login.microsoftonline.com for B2C tenant as well and access KV or Storage using that token.

There is an active feedback regarding this feature here that you can upvote: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/c6da0877-b625-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789

Refer to similar issue discussed here with workarounds:

1. [How to authorize Azure B2C user to read blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69788250/how-to-authorize-azure-b2c-user-to-read-blob-storage)
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/31947/get-access-to-azure-blob-storage-and-key-vault-fro.html

Hope this helps. Please let me know if you need any further assistance. Thank you!

Comment: SKishor-MSFT!
Do you possibly know what can the Bearer Token I get back from B2C when a user logs in be used for?
I'm thinking of creating a custom B2C flow where I trigger an Azure Function and include a SAS token in the claim back to the client. I just cannot figure out how to create a SAS token that only have access to what the user have access to.